# esp8266 amica devuelve esto "ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)"

Tags: arduino, esp8266

¿A qué se deben estos datos que me devuelve el monitor serial? Quiero que me muestre los datos de un dht22 y no logro entender qué está pasando.

```
15:13:30.519 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)
15:13:30.565 -> 
15:13:30.565 -> wdt reset
15:13:30.565 -> load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16 
15:13:30.565 -> tail 4
15:13:30.565 -> chksum 0xcc
15:13:30.565 -> load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4 
15:13:30.565 -> tail 4
15:13:30.565 -> chksum 0xc9
15:13:30.565 -> csum 0xc9
15:13:30.565 -> v00043430
15:13:30.565 -> ~ld
```

Este es el código que estoy usando

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // Incluimos Libreria

#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN 7
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht = DHT(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

String nombreRed = "nombrered";
String contraseniaRed = "contrasenia";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // Inicializamos el monitor serie a 115200 baudios
  crearConexion(nombreRed, contraseniaRed); // Realizamos la conexion a la red wifi
  dht.begin();
  pinMode(DHTPIN, INPUT);

}

void loop() 
{
  sensorDht();  
  
}


void crearConexion(String nombreRed, String contraseniaRed)
{
  WiFi.begin(nombreRed, contraseniaRed); // Nombre de la red, Contraseña de la red

  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) // Se checkea la conexion
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Conexion realizada con exito");
  Serial.println("Conectado a la red wifi: " + String(WiFi.SSID()));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}




void sensorDht()
{
  float temperatura = dht.readTemperature();
  float humedad = dht.readHumidity();

  Serial.println("Temperatura: ");
  Serial.println(temperatura);
  Serial.println("Humedad: ");
  Serial.println(humedad);

  //delay(5000);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]